# Fetch data from JSON with powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I have without success tried to figure out how to most efficiently fetch data with powershell from the below JSON that is returned to me by a REST API:

```
    {
  "$schema": "api:standardResponse",
  "links": [
    {
      "rel": "canonical",
      "href": "http://localhost:8501/services/v2/replicats",
      "mediaType": "application/json"
    },
    {
      "rel": "self",
      "href": "http://localhost:8501/services/v2/replicats",
      "mediaType": "application/json"
    },
    {
      "rel": "describedby",
      "href": "http://localhost:8501/services/v2/metadata-catalog/replicats",
      "mediaType": "application/schema+json"
    }
  ],
  "messages": [],
  "response": {
    "$schema": "ogg:collection",
    "items": [
      {
        "links": [
          {
            "rel": "parent",
            "href": "http://localhost:8501/services/v2/replicats",
            "mediaType": "application/json"
          },
          {
            "rel": "canonical",
            "href": "http://localhost:8501/services/v2/replicats/RNIMDA00",
            "mediaType": "application/json"
          }
        ],
        "$schema": "ogg:collectionItem",
        "name": "RNIMDA00"
      },
      {
        "links": [
          {
            "rel": "parent",
            "href": "http://localhost:8501/services/v2/replicats",
            "mediaType": "application/json"
          },
          {
            "rel": "canonical",
            "href": "http://localhost:8501/services/v2/replicats/RNIMDA01",
            "mediaType": "application/json"
          }
        ],
        "$schema": "ogg:collectionItem",
        "name": "RNIMDA01"
      },
      {
        "links": [
          {
            "rel": "parent",
            "href": "http://localhost:8501/services/v2/replicats",
            "mediaType": "application/json"
          },
          {
            "rel": "canonical",
            "href": "http://localhost:8501/services/v2/replicats/RNIMDA02",
            "mediaType": "application/json"
          }
        ],
        "$schema": "ogg:collectionItem",
        "name": "RNIMDA02"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I only need the data from the "name": node, and the data from the "href": node.

I have done some searching and found som examples where the JSON is converted with **ConvertFrom-Json** and then iterated with a foreach like the pseudo code below:

```
$users = $response | ConvertFrom-Json
foreach ($user in $users)

{

write-host "$($user.name) has the email: $($user.email)"

}
```

But I wonder if there is a better way of fetching data with powershell from a object that contains JSON.

Thanks :)

Comment: What problem are you having with the `ConvertFrom-Json` solution you already found?

Comment: `$Users.response.items.name`

Comment: The json you posted is invalid.

Comment: @jkiiski - I just thought there would be better ways to fetch data from a object with structed data than iterating through it.

Comment: @Theo - I know. I should have mentioned that I only posted a subset of the full JSON dataset as it would be too large for the post. Thank you for pointing it out

Comment: Subset or not, you could make sure the json is valid so we can work with it.

Comment: If you want to get data out of multiple items, you of course have to iterate over those items somehow. PowerShell does do some of the iteration implicitly for you, but you will need to iterate over the items manually, e.g. `$data.response.items | % { [pscustomobject]@{ Name = $_.name; Links = $_.links.href } }`. Here the links will be retrieved implicitly, rather than you having to write a second loop for them.

Comment: @Theo - you are absolutely right. I have updated and validated the JSON. Thank you for pointing that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not really clear what your desired output should be.

Let's assume you have the JSON data converted in a variable $json using `$json = $response | ConvertFrom-Json`

Then if you do:

```
$json.response.items | Select-Object name, @{Name = 'href'; Expression = {$_.links.href}}
```

You will get objects with a `name` and a `href` property, where the `href` will be an array.

PowerShell would output this on screen as

```
name     href                                                                                               
----     ----                                                                                               
RNIMDA00 {http://localhost:8501/services/v2/replicats, http://localhost:8501/services/v2/replicats/RNIMDA00}
RNIMDA01 {http://localhost:8501/services/v2/replicats, http://localhost:8501/services/v2/replicats/RNIMDA01}
RNIMDA02 {http://localhost:8501/services/v2/replicats, http://localhost:8501/services/v2/replicats/RNIMDA02}
```

If however you would like to return an object for each of the href values inside the links nodes you can do:

```
$json.response.items | ForEach-Object {
    $name = $_.name
    foreach ($link in $_.links) {
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            name = $name
            href = $link.href
       }
    }
}
```

which will output

```
name     href                                                
----     ----                                                
RNIMDA00 http://localhost:8501/services/v2/replicats         
RNIMDA00 http://localhost:8501/services/v2/replicats/RNIMDA00
RNIMDA01 http://localhost:8501/services/v2/replicats         
RNIMDA01 http://localhost:8501/services/v2/replicats/RNIMDA01
RNIMDA02 http://localhost:8501/services/v2/replicats         
RNIMDA02 http://localhost:8501/services/v2/replicats/RNIMDA02
```

Answer (score -1):

[jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/) is what you need.

Just install the windows version, add it to your `PATH` (depending on how you installed it) and use the following command:

> curl -s "https://your-url" | jq -r '.response.items.links.href'

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I would have hoped for a more native powershell solution :)